# How to Listview updated after delete database?

Tags: android

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

lv.refreshDrawableState();
```

is not working.

Comment: can you post more code for better understanding.

Comment: what is your problem..? Are you deleting in a listview or in database....if you are deleting in the listview than clear your adapter and call notiftyDatasetChanged on your adapter....

Answer (score 1):

Clear its all data from list/string[] etc which you have passed in adapter and notify call notifyDataSetChange() of your adapter class object.

```
youlist.clear();
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```